# React Big Calendar Add Date Picker Instead Of Today Button

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to add a date picker instead of "Today" button. How can I make this?

If it is with only "Custom Toolbar" can you guys link a demo for that?

If it can't be happen I want to do this out of the calendar. When I choose a date it has to navigate. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution myself but outside of calendar. I added a datepicker and onchange={(date) => setDefaultDate(date) }. After that in <Calendar /> I used the "date" prop and "onNavigate" prop like that : <Calendar
                date={defaultDate}
                onNavigate={(date) => setDefaultDate(date)} /> It is working and it can be enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by providing a custom Toolbar component.

```js
const { Navigate } from 'react-big-calendar';

export default function CustomToolbar({ date, view, views, label, onView, onNavigate, localizer }) {
  // this only works if `newDate` is a true JS Date
  const onPickerChange = (newDate) => onNavigate(Navigate.DATE, newDate); 
  // ... the rest of your Toolbar display
}
```

Then

```js
<Calendar components={{toolbar: CustomToolbar}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to provide your own `Toolbar`, you can add your own component for date picker (for example MUI) and use the `onNavigate` prop as mentioned in the docs https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--on-navigate